# E1 selection rules for transitions between two Σ states

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

For *E1 selection rules* (embodied in the electronic transition moment), to have an allowed transition the direct product of irreducible representations (IRs) must contain the totally symmetric IR. So, for transitions between two $\Sigma$ states, the following transitions are symmetry allowed: $\Sigma^- \leftrightarrow \Sigma^-$ and $\Sigma^+ \leftrightarrow \Sigma^+$.

But I read in Herzberg's book *"Molecular Spectra and Molecular Structure I: Spectra of Diatomic Molecules"* that in *Hund's case b* when we have a rotational distortion of the electronic motion or spin-orbit interaction, the $\Sigma^- \leftrightarrow \Sigma^+$  transition can appear.

Although for rotational distortion I understood that this violation is due to the $- \leftrightarrow +$ rule. I am wondering whether the direct product rule does not apply anymore?

Could you please tell me if there are other cases to consider where the $\Sigma^- \leftrightarrow \Sigma^+$ transition is allowed? And did I misunderstood the selection rule governing the transitions between two $\Sigma$ states?

Comment: The z transition dipole belongs to $A_1\equiv \sum^+$ symmetry species so product $\sum^+\times  \sum^+\times \sum^+\equiv A_1$ and similarly $\sum^-\times  \sum^+\times \sum^-\equiv A_1$. If there is spin orbit 'distortion' which has symmetry $A_2\equiv \sum^-$ then the case is $(\sum^+\times \sum^- )\times  \sum^+\times \sum^-\equiv A_1$ so is allowed

Comment: Thank you very much porphyrin for your answer, it is clearer now.